# Page Refresh on popup close and losing page data

Tags: sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have a repeater as user control and other fields in my SharePoint site page. I need to add records to repeater with help of modal dialog. Whatever has been selected in the popup should come to repeater. Whenever I close the popup, I am able to refresh the page, but the page is losing the other fields' data and repeater too.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed this issue with dopostback using the below snippet.

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```